# Extracting a type from the keys of nested objects

Tags: typescript

So, I have JSON data, consisting of nested objects, and I'm trying to get the unique set of second-level keys as a type. For example:

```
const json = {
    'alice': {
        'dogs': 1,
        'birds': 4,
    },
    'bob': {
        'dogs': 2,
        'cats': 5,
    },
}

type animals1 = keyof typeof json['alice'] | keyof typeof json['bob']
// animas1 = 'dogs' | 'birds' | 'cats'

type animals2 = keyof typeof json['alice' | 'bob']
// animals2 = 'dogs'

type people = keyof typeof json
type animals3 = keyof typeof json[people]
// animals3 = 'dogs'
```

What I want is to be able to get `'dogs' | 'birds' | 'cats'` (as per animals1), without having to manually specify the first-level keys. However, the construct that I'm attempting to use to do that (animals3) seems to be only showing the intersect of all keys, rather than the union.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Like this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=50&pln=16&pc=51#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVhcMC8MDeAoG2YHICGANgJbACmuAXOljnbgCYgDmEVMAjADS13a4AjYgCcGbagBYedAL7ScgkAPaY+Cpq3YAmeWtzB8UcTACsumHIwyMGAPS2YACyhQADhEr3o+YAGsQAG5kwgBmhCAA7gB0oAC2tvi2JgAMAMwA7CZaABwAbLYcEtkcqSbp6RhQAJ6uZDAAqmDE4AAqIACSYFDBEGTAUM1gADz1AHwoMLQAFPUwZAAe3WBiMPhgVTAA-DBTvtT1AJTIowEgxAww1GBkQcIHc4tkyxA7u9TEYCHBMO1HJ2cMe7bdqXGDXW42aq1VZNWJECAcCa+MhVEAhBpNVodLo9PoDcBDKFkNHwRBgADayNR6KJJIQ4AAuqM7A41sQ4QiJowWGwYAAfPBCUS8gX6QxsDBAA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating of union of the second level keys by mapping over the keys of T and then flattening them using `[keyof T]`:

```
type UnionOfSecondLevelKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: keyof T[K]
}[keyof T];

const json = {
  'alice': {
    'dogs': 1,
    'birds': 4,
  },
  'bob': {
    'dogs': 2,
    'cats': 5,
  },
};

type animals = UnionOfSecondLevelKeys<typeof json>;
// animals = "dogs" | "birds" | "cats"
```